# Why sending ether from a smart contract is a security risk?

Tags: solidity, security

In [this example](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/solidity-by-example.html#simple-open-auction) from the Solidity documentation, inside the `bid` function, there is this comment:

> Sending back the money by simply using highestBidder.send(highestBid) is a security risk because it could execute an untrusted contract. It is always safer to let the recipient withdraw their money themselves.

Why would this be a security risk? Can someone provide an example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If `highestBidder` is a contract address. It can prevent you from sending Ether to it or Reentrancy Attack

Examples:

- https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x43BA674B4fbb8B157b7441C2187bCdD2cdF84FD5
- https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/re-entrancy/

Answer (score 0):

It would be a risk due to several possible reasons.
For example if your contract functioning depends on the ether being received by A, a malicious user may enter the address of some smart contract B as A. However, B would simply not accept any payments in eth, which would probably cause your contract to not function as expected.
Another possible attack could be a re-entrancy attack.

Answer (score 0):

When sending ether to an external contract your contract may fall victim to a denial of service or reentrancy attack.

[pull payment](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/payment#PullPayment)